# Can't use clear command on terminal (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, terminal, xterm

Every time I try to use the command `clear` in a terminal window, I can't because:

`'dtterm': unknown terminal type.`

or

`'xterm': unknown terminal type.`

or

`'ansi': unknown terminal type.`

I tried changing the terminal types on the preference menu, but without success. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminal.app is setting the [`TERM`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-TERM) environment variable according to the menu entry, so exporting it does not address the problem.  (Setting `TERM` has [*no effect*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-nsterm-bce) on the behavior of Terminal.app, but that is a different mattern).

OSX (and most Unix-like) systems use *terminfo* for finding terminal information.  If the environment variable [`TERMINFO`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-TERMINFO) is set, the ncurses library uses *that* path in preference to the compiled-in location (which is supposed to match the installed-location).

Your shell may have set the `TERMINFO` variable (for instance, by copying settings from another machine). Removing it from the shell initialization (such as `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`) is a way to fix that.

Alternatively, you may (as in *[tput: unknown terminal “xterm-256color”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798940/tput-unknown-terminal-xterm-256color/32800502#32800502)*) have installed some not-mentioned package which conflicts with the ncurses libraries on the system.  In that discussion, it seems that someone built ncurses libraries which had compiled-in default for `TERMINFO` to a non-existent location.  For that case, I pointed out that the OP could set `TERMINFO` to tell the broken libraries where to find the terminal database.  That is,

```
export TERMINFO=/usr/share/terminfo
```

would be a first step.

Answer (score 3):

Define the TERM environment variable:

```
# export TERM=xterm
```

This change is valid just for the current Terminal session. If you want to make it permanent you have to add that export to your `~/.bashrc` file. If you want to make the change permanent for all the users you can edit the `/etc/profile` file or add a new file in `/etc/profile.d/`

Answer (score 0):

This code is work for me.

```
TERM="rxvt-256color"
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?