# tput: unknown terminal "xterm-256color"

Tags: ncurses, terminfo

I'm running OS X 10.10.5.  I'm getting an error trying to open a terminal:

tput: unknown terminal "xterm-256color"

This is obviously a missing termcap entry.

```
$ port list ncurses
ncurses                        @6.0            devel/ncurses
```

Any ideas how to install 'ncurses-term' on OS X?

```
$ sudo port install ncurses-term
Password:
Error: Port ncurses-term not found
```

Comment: What's ncurses-term?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804208/nano-error-error-opening-terminal-xterm-256color

Comment: "... I started getting this error on certain (Debian/Ubuntu) servers ... This worked for me on a Ubuntu server ..." - `ncurses-term` is a debian package.

Comment: Yup.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Yes, the other answers on that page (those that apply to OS X).

Comment: None of the comments on that page appear particularly relevant to this question.

Comment: By the way, it is not "termcap", but "terminfo".  Almost no one uses real termcap nowadays, except for people maintaining museum systems.

Comment: Understood.  infocmp 
infocmp: couldn't open terminfo file /Users/aaronmeurer/anaconda/envs/_build_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_/share/terminfo/78/xterm-256color.   Aaron Meurer works @Contiuum.  How did this get into my system? (I use the Anaconda Stack). So do you know a solution?

Comment: I was busy.  But from your comments, it seems that my answer got you to see that you had conflicting ncurses libraries (or applications) due to using more than one package manager.  The [thread](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/XKMFYqM12Vg) has no useful analysis, but looking at the [git](git://github.com/ContinuumIO/conda-recipes.git) history, it seems the packager had built the binaries with the wrong path.  Nothing in the `build.sh` would have prevented you from working around the problem by setting `TERMINFO` to point *to* the working terminal database.

Answer (score 6):

The problem was with an Anaconda package:

```
https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/XKMFYqM12Vg
```

It appears there is some problem with an earlier version of the ncurses package that interferes with terminfo

```
conda install -c r ncurses
```

Comment: rather do `conda install -c anaconda ncurses`

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding the existence of bloated/monolithic packages on Linux, the package maintainers for ncurses packages often split up the 7Mb of terminfo into "base" and "term" chunks (and separate it from the library).  The MacPorts maintainer for ncurses has not done this.  The terminal database is part of the ["ncurses"](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=library&substr=ncurses) package.  For instance, I see this from

```
port contents ncurses@6.0_0+universal
```

under /opt:

```
/opt/local/share/terminfo/73/screen.xterm-256color
```

Also there is a system (non-port) copy here:

```
/usr/share/terminfo/78/xterm-256color
```

Applications linked with ncurses will generally use one or the other, depending on whether they are linked with the port- or system-library. However, ncurses can be told to look some other place by setting the [`TERMINFO`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-TERMINFO) variable.  If you happen to have copied some customization from another machine into your `.bashrc`, that could have set `TERMINFO`.

By itself, [`tput`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html) gives no clue where it is looking for a terminal entry.  You can check the output from `env` to see if `TERMINFO` is set.  The [`infocmp`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/infocmp.1m.html#h3-Other-Options) utility can show where it looks (since [late 2011](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20111217)), using the `-D` option, e.g.,

```
$ infocmp -D
/usr/local/ncurses/share/terminfo
/usr/share/terminfo
/opt/local/share/terminfo
```

By the way, OSX does not (barring some specialized ports) use *termcap* as such.  It uses *terminfo*, as part of some given release of ncurses (see for example the manual page for [`tgetent`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/curs_termcap.3x.html)).

Comment: I have these files ... $ ls -l /opt/local/share/terminfo/73/screen.xterm-256color
-rw-r--r--  1 root  admin  3238 Aug 20 08:53 /opt/local/share/terminfo/73/screen.xterm-256color
$ ls -l /usr/share/terminfo/78/xterm-256color
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  3322 Sep  9  2014 /usr/share/terminfo/78/xterm-256color